# What is the purpose of RxJs Subscription and unsubscribe when it not needed?

Tags: rxjs

I have seen the following code in an angular application. In the code, a `Subscription` is being used to `subscribe` and `unsubscribe`. I don't understand why a `Subscription` is used. Is there any benefit in using this pattern?

```
public routeChangeSub$: Subscription;

this.routeChangeSub$ = this.route.firstChild.paramMap
        .subscribe((map: ParamMap) =>
          this.getRouteParams(map));

this.routeChangeSub$.unsubscribe();

getRouteParams(map: ParamMap): number {
    const characterId = map.get('id');
    let id: number = null;
    if (characterId) {
      this.character$ = this.store.pipe(
        select(selectCharacterById, { id: characterId })
      );
      id = parseInt(characterId, 10);
    }
    return id;
  }
```

**Update:**

How this can be different from

```
this.route.firstChild.paramMap
        .subscribe((map: ParamMap) =>
          this.getRouteParams(map));

getRouteParams(map: ParamMap): number {
    const characterId = map.get('id');
    let id: number = null;
    if (characterId) {
      this.character$ = this.store.pipe(
        select(selectCharacterById, { id: characterId })
      );
      id = parseInt(characterId, 10);
    }
    return id;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An observable (which is the type of `route.firstChild.paramMap`) will not emit anything unless something is subscribed to it.

In this file, the author explicitly subscribes to `paramMap` to trigger a state change by calling `getRouteParams()`. Then they immediately unsubscribe. If they didn't unsubscribe, the subscription will continue to run which may cause state issues and memory leaks.

A far simpler solution is to use the `take(1)` operator. This will take an emitted value (the `1` is the number of values to take) then will send a `complete` signal to the subscription. This causes the subscription to automatically unsubscribe.

```
this.route.firstChild.paramMap.pipe(
  take(1),
  tap(map=>this.getRouteParams(map))
).subscribe();
```

Because we're using `take()`, we don't need to assign the subscription to a property. The observable will emit one value, and will invoke `getRouteParams()` before unsubscribing.

Note: If you're not aware, `tap()` is the operator to use if you want to apply an effect to any state property outside of the observable.

Comment: I updated the question with one more additional one. Can I just ignore ```Subscription``` altogether and don't use it at all as I have shown?

Comment: `Subscription` is just the type declaration used when a property is assigned to `observable$.subscribe()`. In your updated example, you are subscribing to `paramMap`. However, you don't have a way to unsubscribe because you have no reference to the subscription. If you assign this subscription to a property, its type becomes `Subscription`.

Comment: Should I use ```Subscription``` declaration to achieve what ```getRouteParams``` doing? What is the disadvantage of not using it?

Comment: Since this is using TypeScript, yes you should make your types as explicit as possible. In your example, you should assign the subscription to a property so you can unsubscribe later. If you don't unsubscribe, that will cause state/memory issues. But if you use my example, you don't need to assign the subscription to a property and you don't need to manually unsubscribe.

Comment: How your code and the code that I added in the **update** section of the question different? What if I don't use ```take``` or ```tap``` but call ```getRouteParams``` in the ```subscribe``` method. I'm trying to understand what benefits I get with explicit declaration or even with ```tap``` and ```take``` which subscribe and unsubscribe. In the case of angular, when a page where this code is used is navigated away, isn't the subscription is unsubscribed and as a result there wont be any memory leak?

Comment: Even in Angular, you need to manage subscriptions inside each component, and unsubscribe when that component is no longer needed. Otherwise those subscriptions will stay in memory. The largest difference between your updated example and mine, is that yours will not unsubscribe, and will sit in memory.

Comment: Because RxJS comes with many helpful operators (the items inside a `.pipe()`) it is more optimal to use them and keep your subscription function as simple as possible. As by this example, `take(1)` is more optimal than assigning a subscription, then immediately unsubscribing after its definition. The original example just so happens to work because `paramMap` immediately emits a value, but this is not always the case with observables.